# Is there a way to onCreateOptionsMenus() continue "listening" while a Progress Dialog is showing?

Tags: android

The Title is almost the entire question but i'll complement it with some things :

-(1) I have a AsyncTask for get some data from Internet
-(2) I have a AsyncTask for display a Progress Dialog

Before call (1) , I execute (2) dialog.show() and when task (2) ends I call dialog.dimiss(). All is doing right , but while the Progress Bar is showing the Menu Button stay unresponsiveness, ie , nothing happens...

I would like to know if it is the default behavior or i missing something ?

I'm looking for it and did found anything that clear me about it..

Aprecciate any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean to say that while the dialog is showing, pressing the hard menu button does not bring up the menu. Did I get it right?

If so, then I see the same behavior as you. But according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html):

> For example, when a dialog is open,
>   the Menu key reveals the options menu
>   defined for the Activity and the
>   volume keys modify the audio stream
>   used by the Activity.

So I would expect that the menu button should still work even if the dialog is showing, but based on my experience, it does not.

After the dialog is dismissed, the menu button should work again.

Comment: Exactly..i would like to know if it is a default behavior and if i can change this behavior...

Comment: Just to complement... the dialog progress is running on a AsyncTask.. in onPreExecute() i call dialog.show(), in doInBackground() is waiting for some data and onPostExecute() i call dialog.dismiss(). But like you said and in my tests seems that dialog.show() blocks the ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` is meant to *prepare* the dialog.  Once it is shown and in use it is no longer being *prepared* and thus use of the dialog is then handled in `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: Yeah, i know it, but what i'm trying to say is that my menu is openned in onCreateOptionsMenu using inflater, and it works fine. The problem is when the progress dialog is showning and the menu button doesn't listen anymore...